# how to insert file in library and insert data from that file in sharepoint online in SPFX react

Tags: document-library

how to insert file in library and insert data from that file in sharepoint online in SPFX react
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code snippet that demonstrates how to upload a file to a library and insert data from that file in SharePoint Online using SPFX React and File Upload API:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/files";

async function uploadFile(file: File, libraryName: string) {
  try {
    const fileUrl = '/${libraryName}/${file.name}';

    // Upload the file to the library
    await sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/${libraryName}').files.add(file.name, file, true);

    // Get the file's content
    const response = await sp.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUrl).getBuffer();
    const content = new TextDecoder().decode(response);

    // Insert the file's content in SharePoint using the REST API
    const list = sp.web.lists.getByTitle(libraryName);
    const listItem = await list.items.add({
      Title: file.name,
      Content: content
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: hey i use the same code but i'm getting error Property 'getFolderByServerRelativeUrl' does not exist on type 'IWeb & IInvokable<any>'. Did you mean 'getFolderByServerRelativePath'?ts(2551)
web.d.ts(24, 9): 'getFolderByServerRelativePath' is declared here. so how can i resolve this